# Faster Alternative for looping in combination with If in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, tidy

I have a data frame with 2,000,000 + rows and 22 columns.
In three of the columns the entries are either 0, 1 or NA.
I want to have a column which has the sum of these three columns for every row, treating NA as 0.
Using a for loop is definitely way too slow.

Have you got any alternatives for me? Another idea was using mutate in a pipe, but I have problems selecting the columns that I want to add up by name.

First attempt:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(T12)){

  if(is.na(T12$blue[i])  & is.na(T12$blue.y[i])) {
  
    T12$blue[i] <- T12$blue.x[i]
  
  }else if(is.na(T12$blue[i])  & is.na(T12$blue.x[i])){
  
  
    T12$blue[i] <- T12$blue.y[i]
  }else if(is.na(T12$blue[i])  & is.na(T12$blue.x[i]) & is.na(T12$blue.y[i]) )
    T12[i,] <- NULL
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that the columns you wish to add are the first three. If you need different columns,  just change `c(1,2,3)` in the code below.

```
apply(T12[,c(1,2,3)], 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Note: @27ϕ9  comments that a faster solution is

```
rowSums(T12[,c(1,2,3)], 1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: No in my dataframe the specific columns are number 8,15,22. They need to be detected by name.

Comment: Why can't you just replace c(1,2,3) with c(8,15,22)  ? Are the names you need blue, blue.x and blue.y ?

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace all the NA's to 0.

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
setDT(df)[,newcol := a + b + c]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object column names are `a`, `b` and `c`, maybe you can try the code below

```
within(T12, new <- rowSums(cbind(a,b,c),na.rm = TRUE))
```